# Interpolation in MATLAB, Newton's Divided Difference

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have been working on a MATLAB code about Interpolation, specifically Newton's Divided Difference. So in this code, the input variables are time t, velocity v, and desired time tdesired, and order; while the output of the function should be the coefficients and interpolated velocity at tdesired.

At the end, I should be able to return the B coeffs, and interpolated value (v). For some reason, it's showing that there's an error.

File: solution.m Line: 3 Column: 46
Invalid expression. Check for missing multiplication operator, missing or unbalanced delimiters, or other syntax error. To construct matrices, use brackets instead of parentheses.

This is the function that I have currently worked on:

solution.m

```
function [bc_nd,v_newton] = ndd(t,v,tdesired,2)
    n = length(v);
    b = zeros(n,n);
   % Assigning dependent variable to b
    b(I, 1) = v(:);
    for j = 2:n
        for i = 1:n - j + 1
            b(i,j) = (b(i+j, j-1) - b(i, j-1))/(t(i+j-1) - t(i));
        end
    end
   % Finite Divided Difference to interpolate
    dv = 1;
    v = b(1,1);
    for j = 1:n-1
        dt = dt*(tdesired-t(j));
        dv = dv+b(1,j+1)*dt;
    end
end
```

```
[t,v,tdesired] = data();

% Calculates the coefficients of quadratic polynomial and vdesired value using Newton's Divided Difference Method
[bc_nd,v_newton] = ndd(t,v,tdesired,2)
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `data()` or some dummy values for `t`, `v`, and `tdesired` so we can reproduce your error.

Comment: I think your issue might be that you are trying to pass a constant as a variable. You need to pass the variable `order` instead of the constant `2` --> `ndd(t,v,tdesired,order)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a function argument as a value, i.e.

```
function [bc_nd,v_newton] = ndd(t,v,tdesired,2)
```

You can't have a `2` there. Either define it inside, or make it a variable and pass it when you call it.

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify, I'd have to make it into function [bc_nd,v_newton] = ndd(t,v,tdesired,order) instead, right?